# Implement shopify templates in django

Tags: django, shopify

I bought Ella Shopify template because of its awesome design look to implement it in Django project in rush. After buying it I found that it isn't a standard html5 css3 template with bunch of ".liquid" files. But when I opened few files I found that the template language is similar. I need to know is it possible to use ".liquid" files for a Shopify theme in Django. Please advise because I really love this template.

Template I bought is at http://themeforest.net/item/ella-responsive-shopify-template/9691007.

At least can I transform ".liquid" files into HTML5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change .liquid file extension to .html and for any css and js with .liquid extension to .html as well. Make sure your context is coming up from python code because the template you mention requires you to create a shopify ID and then it will render the context from shopify processor.

There are ways for you to even make python context processors work with .liquid files but I won't recommend it. You will complicate your project.

Comment: Lolz...it worked perfectly fine though it was lengthy to figure out context rendered by shopify theme from their server. But when I changed those to Python views based context it worked perfectly fine. Thanks